# C++ - Cannot pass derived type as base type list to constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14

I'm trying to implement a class which is constructed from a variable number of different implementations of the same abstract base class.
Here's a minimal example:

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void something() const = 0;
}
```

There are two classes (Derived1 and Derived2) which are dervied from that base:

```
class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    void something() const override {
        std::cout << "derived 1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    void something() const override {
        std::cout << "derived 2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

What I want to do is to pass instances of those classes to another class (Collection) via constructor. I have tried to achieve this using a std::initializer_list:

```
class Collection {
public:
    Collection(std::initializer_list<Base> args) {
        for(auto& arg: args) {
            arg.something();
        }
    }
};
```

When I then try to call that constructor like this

```
Derived1 d1;
Derived2 d2;
Collection col({d1, d2});
```

it does not compile. Here's the error messages that I'm getting:

> cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Base'
>   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Base':
>   'virtual void Base::something() const'

It looks like it needs to construct an instance of the abstract base class, but why? I would expect that it has something to do with a copy constructor being called within the initializer list class, but I get no error indicating this is the case.
I feel like I'm missing something incredibly basic here, I just can't seem to find it...

Comment: See object slicing. and `Base` cannot be instantiated on its own.

Comment: you need to use pointers or references for polymorphism. One reason is that objects have different sizes, references dont

Comment: [Relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659892/abstract-class-as-stdinitializer-list-object)

Comment: Ok, this does make sense. I did at one point try to use a std::initializer_list<Base&> which also didn't work. But I guess that wouldn't make much sense anyway because the initializer list would already use references internally... Would a reference wrapper work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It looks like it needs to construct an instance of the abstract base class

No, you cannot create an instance of an abstract base class. Instead, you create instances of derived classes and then use base class references or pointers to that instance.

What you are trying to do is comparable to

```
Derived1 d1; // Ok, create subclass instance
Base b = d1; // Not ok, copies only the Base part of d1, discards the rest
```

This is called object slicing. You can instead go with

```
Base& b1 = d1; // Ok, reference to d1 doesn't copy/slice anything
Base *b2 = &d1; // Pointers are ok, too
```

Applied to your scenario, you could define the constructor for `Collection` as

```
Collection(std::initializer_list<const Base*> args) {
    for(auto *arg: args) {
        arg->something();
    }
}
```

and instantiate it via

```
Collection col({&d1, &d2});
```

Comment: This does look encouranging. Is there a way I could do the same with rvalue refs instead of pointers, so I could instantiate directly in the constructor call like this: `Collection col({Derived1, Derived2});` or something similar?

Comment: Do you intend to use the temporaries only for calling a member function on them as shown in the example? Or are they supposed to be stored somewhere?

Comment: I would store them in the Collection class.

Comment: You can pass raw pointers to newly created instances with `Collection col({new Derived1(), new Derived2()});` and store/mange them with a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` data member. It would be preferable to pass `std::unique_ptr` objects directly, though. This isn't feasible with `std:initializer_list` though or a container ctor argument initialized with `std::initializer_list`, you can read about this e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type/8469002#8469002).

Comment: Yes, that's the point I'm struggling with. I want the caller side (the Collection constructor) to be as short/simple as possible, so ideally `Collection col({Derived1, Derived2});` but `new` would still be ok. I usually try to avoid `new` calls, but I guess there is no better way here. Would I need to `delete` the pointer after moving to the `std::unique_ptr` in the constructor?

Comment: No, neither `std::move` anything, nor `delete` it. If you construct an object with `std::unique_ptr(someRawPointer)`, deletion is handled for you.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot! I ended up using a slightly different approach as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659892/abstract-class-as-stdinitializer-list-object). It is somewhat ugly but it works. It uses a template on the constructor and rvalue references as the arguments. This allows for my desired call signature.

Comment: Sounds good. But l think it's wrong and evil to call code posted by T.C. "ugly" :)

Comment: I apologise for the blasphemy!

Answer (score 4):

`std::initializer_list<Base>` is a collection of objects whose **most-derived-type** is `Base`. Such a collection can't exist, because `Base` is abstract.

You probably want a collection of *pointers* or *references* to `Base`, e.g. `std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<Base>>`